# method eel.addText doesn't exist yet can run dispiting Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm trying to modify [this python file](https://github.com/yoursamlan/pubsidian/blob/afba8420dfd80df8579a87f09ca793ec47c4d072/tools/GUI/PubsidianConverter.py#L46) on GitHub with VS Code on Mac. And Pylance keeps complaining `"addText" is not a known member of module Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues` on this line

```py
eel.addText("<b style='color:green;'>data.json has been created successfully.</b>")
```

I'm sure it's not an error because I copied this file to a new folder and it runs correctly.

However when I check the eel source code in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eel/__init__.py` searching "addText", there's no result.

- `pip3 list | grep Eel` shows `Eel  0.10.4`
- `python3 --version` shows `Python 3.9.9`

Could you explain why is this happening? How can I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of simple, nothing to do with Python/Pylance. `eel.addText()` will call the function `addText` in `<script>` exposed in the `app.html` ([see file from the same repo](https://github.com/yoursamlan/pubsidian/blob/afba8420dfd80df8579a87f09ca793ec47c4d072/tools/GUI/web/app.html#L161)) passed to `eel.start('app.html')`.
But I still don't know how to suppress this error.